# how to create selectAll checkbox in JSF-2

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, selectall

how can I create select All checkbox in JSF -2 to select all select boxes in the page only not on the other page as these check boxes are the list and displaying 20 in each page...

Thanks,
alex

Comment: Have you reached your goal with the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For example, you can load your checkboxes within `<f:form>` with

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="{#myBean.checkAll}">
    <f:ajax render="checkboxes">
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="checkboxes">
    <ui:repeat var="check" value="#{myBean.checkBoxes}">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value=#{check.checked}/>
    <h:outputText value=#{check.checkedCaption}/>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Then you can check them all with the following bean method and partial page update:

```
public void checkAll(ActionEvent event){
    for(Check check : checkBoxes) {
        checkBoxes.setChecked(true);
    }
 }
```

The uncheck all functionality can be achieved in the following manner, when you replace true in action listener method with the opposite of the current check box state.

**Edit**. If you want to perform server-side setting of checked properties later, for example during save button click, you may want to check/uncheck the checkbuttons on the client. So, if you are using jQuery 1.6+, you may call `$('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);` presetting `styleClass="checkbox"` of `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` in your view. To do this, you may, for example, bind javascript onclick method of a button with the simple javascript proposed above.